# Strange behaviour while initializing time with JODA's DateTime() constructor on Android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, jodatime

I faced strange behaviour of JODA's time constructor.

So I execute following lines

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime("1972-01-01T10:00:00.000+00:00");
DateTime d2 = new DateTime("1970-01-01T10:00:00.000+00:00");
String s1 = d1.toString();
String s2 = d2.toString();
```

and see that

```
s1 = 1972-01-01T10:00:00.000Z
s2 = 1970-01-01T11:00:00.000+01:00
```

Ok, I know about default time zone for DateTime, but why different calls returns time objects with different timezones?

If you try to change the first year 1972->1971, you see another picture

```
s1 = 1971-01-01T11:00:00.000+01:00
s2 = 1970-01-01T11:00:00.000+01:00
```

My current time zone is +1 (Europe/Berlin).

What have I missed?

Comment: Can't reproduce the behaviour..

Comment: Me neither. With my timezone it is printing the same....1972-01-01T05:00:00.000-05:00
1970-01-01T05:00:00.000-05:00

Comment: Ok guys, thanx for try. Forget to say, it happens on Android, have you tried pure java?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this for `Europe/Berlin` timezone, but that's the result I get with `Europe/London`, for all three years.

And iirc the reason is that in the early 70s the UK was in a period where we stayed on +1 all winter. So the epoch time expressed in Europe/London is actually `1970-01-01T01:00:00+01:00`.